# Windows Phone List Grouping

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox

Is there any simple way to group list items in windows phone `listbox`?

We don't want to use `Silverlight Toolkit` or nested templates.

Comment: try with longlistSelector......http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api

Comment: @ Pradeep Kesharwani , Its again from Toolkit.We don't want any external library.Thanks for your opinion

Comment: You can achieve with nested list box. create your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use the [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class to achieve the grouping. Once one has all the data into the list (the default view before grouping), one can create as many groups as needed off of that and then show them in the list box as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Will check this solution soon